# Apex defined field not accessible in the flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm returning this output from my flow action -

```
global class FlowOutput {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Content')
    @AuraEnabled
    global List<Types.Resource> content;
  }
```

`Type.Resource` class is defined as following -

```
global class Resource {
    @InvocableVariable
    @AuraEnabled
    global String id;

    @InvocableVariable
    @AuraEnabled
    global String type; // file|folder

    @InvocableVariable
    @AuraEnabled
    global String name;

    global Resource(String id, String type, String name) {
      this.id = id;
      this.type = type;
      this.name = name;
    }

    global Resource() {
    }
  }
```

When I try to use the `content` variable in collection filter, I get this error

[image]

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

For the field to be visible in flow, it's class needs to be an outer class. `Resource` was a inner class earlier under `Type`. Moving it out as a outer class solved the problem